# Calling the same function inside a function

Tags: javascript

I am on my second week of learning js and I am stuck on the following simple script. Function checkStr takes the string and a character as parameters and looks for the repeating character in the string. If it finds 2 or more repeating characters it alerts the total number of repeated symbols. If not -the function should return to executing the same function. Can somebody help me to correct the code and make the function work as described? Specifically I need help with returning to executing the same function based on conditions.

```
let str = 'sssxxa';
let res = '';
let count = 0;

function checkStr(str, k) {
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == k) {
      res += str[i];
    }
  }

  if (res.length >= 2)
    alert(res.length);
  else {
    alert('No match');
    return checkStr(str, prompt());
  }
}

checkStr(str, prompt());
```

Comment: Is this actually part of your assignment? Because it does not really make sense to use recursion here. All you probably need is a loop outside the function. If the assignment doesn't specify recursion, then this is probably the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can call another function that puts your `checkStr` into a loop until it achieves the desired results

... Below your code

```js
function loopcheckStr() {
   while (checkStr(str, k) != 1) {
      k = prompt();
}

return 0;
```

and change your it to `return 0` and `return 1` respectively for when you did not and did find your answer